# Why is (int&)0 ill-formed?

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer, static-cast, const-cast

According to [expr.cast]/4, a C-style cast tries the following casts in order:

1. `const_cast`
2. `static_cast`
3. `static_cast` followed by `const_cast`
4. `reinterpret_cast`
5. `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`

The following cast is well-formed:

```
const_cast<int&>(static_cast<const int&>(0))
```

Yet both GCC and Clang [reject](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11bc051ce183b072) the cast `(int&)0`.  Why?

Comment: What would you want it to mean?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm not saying it should be well-formed; I'm saying the rules of the language appear to make it well-formed and I would like someone to point out the error in my reasoning.

Comment: UPDATE: The first (well-formed) cast was not rejected by Clang on my machine.  The second cast was rejected.  Hmm.  Making it a `const int&` it was not rejected.  I'll have to ponder.

Comment: @Justin • I had updated my comment.  I cut-n-pasted the first (good) casts.

Comment: @Eljay Casting to `const int&` is fine because of lifetime extension

Comment: @Peter I disagree that this is a duplicate of that question. This question is focused around why the C-style cast doesn't succeed, not around why the `const&` works

Comment: Reopen-hammered :)

Comment: You might as well ask why `static_cast<int &>0` is rejected  by the compiler, because that is what `(int &)0` resolves to.  And the question I linked to as a dup addresses that.

Comment: @Peter No, that's not how it works. The compiler will accept `float* p; (int*)p;` even though the static cast would be rejected---because it interprets it as a reinterpret cast instead. But in my case, the (third) alternative interpretation is not used.

Comment: I think this question shows the same bugs that your previous one showed. So in a way it's a duplicate.

Comment: @SebastianRedl However, I'm not sure whether the committee would agree that this case (as opposed to the previous one) is supposed to be well-formed. Perhaps a wording change is needed.

Comment: @Brian - I concur about the wording change. Hopefully to something that doesn't leave it open to "interpretation" (pun intended).

Comment: I posted to std-discussion@isocpp.org

Comment: In that context, the ampersand `&` creates an alias to (the name of) an lvalue. The number 0 is not a name or an lvalue.

Comment: It says the first fashion from that list in which the cast “can be interpreted [...] is used, even if a cast resulting from that interpretation is ill-formed”.  I suppose the interpretation as a bare `static_cast` is considered “possible” until [expr.static.cast]/1 forbids that it “cast away constness”.  But that would seem to prevent ever using interpretation #3.

Comment: Related, and possible duplicate: [r-value Reference Casting and Temporary Materialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796854/r-value-reference-casting-and-temporary-materialization/48939852#comment84928372_48939852)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [r-value Reference Casting and Temporary Materialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796854/r-value-reference-casting-and-temporary-materialization)

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66816741/why-does-this-c-style-cast-not-consider-static-cast-followed-by-const-cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [bug in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77465) and [clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30266).

According to [CWG 909](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#909), the "straightforward interpretation of the wording" should be used when generating cast sequences for C-style casts; there, the first cast invokes a conversion operator, but there is no reason to think that it should be any different when the first cast is reference binding a temporary.

I've posted [a patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2021-December/587495.html) to the gcc mailing list, generated from [this git branch](https://github.com/ecatmur/gcc/tree/so-66816741), but it hasn't received any attention so far.